# How much heat does a processor generate?

Tags: c#

Wondering if I can create a heater/ coin miner combo that only turns on when the heater in my house is also on. 
Is that possible? What are the limitations of this type of concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is to leave the fan blowing, while you don't need the temparature in the processor, but in the room. Therefore the fan needs to blow it into your room. Not to say that your processor needs cooling in order to maintain a reasonable life time.

As an collatoral benèfit the fans consumes power, and thus generates also (a little) heat.